# License response codes -- what does a policy actually see?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

In the [docs on server response extras](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#extras), I find this:

> When network problems prevent or interrupt a license check, the Android Market client notifies the application by returning a "RETRY" response code to the Policy's processServerResponse() method. In the case of system problems, such as when the application is unable to bind with Android Market's ILicensingService implementation, the LicenseChecker library itself calls the Policy processServerResonse() method with a "RETRY" response code.

Unfortunately, RETRY is not listed one of the [listed response codes](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#server-response-codes) that the server returns, and when I look at the LVL source code, it appears that the Android Market client actually returns one of the server response codes and it is the LicenseValidator class in the library that decides when to turn that into a RETRY response status.

Furthermore, in the [section on implementing a custom policy](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Policy), there's this in the guidelines:

> Note that the Android Market client automatically retries failed requests, so in most cases there is no need for your Policy to retry them.

I find this confusing. Does the client simply report one of the documented server response codes, or does it do more? If the device is in airplane mode, for instance, does a custom policy need to deal with RETRY or with ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER? Should the policy (or application) deal with retries, or does the client do it automatically?

Comment: There is an additional problem: the method processServerResponse() that is supposed to be overridden by custom policies expects a parameter of datatype "ResponseData", which is a private class in the LVL. So I don't know how one is expected to write a custom policy. :(

Comment: @BarryFruitman - Yeah, there are lots of limitations to the LVL. I ended up rewriting large parts of it, mainly to allow more info to arrive to the application so it can present more informative info to the user.